# Passing parameters to bash from custom Vim commands

Tags: bash, vim, command-line

I have this custom command inside my `.vimrc`:

```
command! Minfo -nargs=1 call s:MappingInfo(<f-args>)
```

The argument of the command is then passed to the MappingInfo function which "pastes" it to bash command using Vim's `execute` concatenation.

The function works fine when I execute it using `:call MappingInfo("something")` but when I try the command: `:Minfo something`, I get the error: `E488: Trailing characters`.

How do I fix error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the name and the arguments number:

```
command! -nargs=1 Minfo call s:MappingInfo(<f-args>)
```